# market place for windows mobile 6.0 apps?

Tags: windows-mobile

i  had seen the below link for market.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Marketplace_for_Mobile

here i'm confusing the below info.

A one-time $99 USD fee for developers to list up to five applications yearly in the store is charged by Microsoft. After the five applications have been listed for the year, each additional application can only be listed with another $99 USD fee.

that means $99 USD fee for developers to list up to five applications  only.next additional  $99  will have to pay for marketing  my apps.

pls tell me clearly  that how to place windows mobile 6.0 apps in market .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call me crazy, but Wikipedia might not be the exact right place to look for this information.  You might want to look on Microsoft page, which has a [landing pad here](http://developer.windowsphone.com/Default.aspx).  You'l find [content](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9730557) and [application](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9730556) policies, [certification requirements](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9732163), [walkthroughs](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/windowsphone/archive/2009/08/24/windows-marketplace-for-mobile-registration-and-application-submission-walkthroughs.aspx), and more.

As of right now Marketplace is supported for WinMo 6.0 and later, though 6.0 and 6.1 devices have to manually install the Marketplace app.

It is a $99 fee to register, which gives you five application registrations.  Once you register and pay the fee, then you go through the submission process, which really is outlined much better in the links above than I could possibly put in a SO answer.